# NGINX Regex location - Starts with X AND does not contain Y

Tags: regex, nginx, configuration

I have the following location config:

```
location ~ ^/(trucks|cars|planes|system|tools) {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htauth_file;
        proxy_set_header Host "server.lan";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080$request_uri;
}
```

When *anyone* makes requests to

> /trucks

or

> /cars

etc, I want them to be authenticated by the basic auth. But when anyone makes requests to

> /trucks?id=123

or

> /cars?id=124

then I want no authentication, taken care of a lower location block.

I basically dont want the location to match when there is a question mark in the URI.

Is there a way to modify my pasted config so that it does not match when there is a question mark in the URI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest the following regex:

```
^/(trucks|cars|planes|system|tools)(?![^\s?]*\?)
```

[DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/tK9aL4/1)

Comment: this worked perfectly! and thanks for providing a demo link.

Answer (score 1):

Try following regex:

```
location ~ ^/[^?]+ {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htauth_file;
        proxy_set_header Host "server.lan";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080$request_uri;
}
```

It will:

```
 /cars <--match
 /trucks <--match
 /trucks?id=123 <-- no match
```

Comment: thank you for your response! I have several location blocks, the very last one has `location /`. I tried using this: `location ~ ^/(trucks|cars)[^?]+` and it did not work for me. Is there another way to modify it so that it will work?

Comment: arguments are ignored when location is being matched, but it possible to have conditional expression inside location block, something like *if ($args ...)*